# Publish fails in Visual Studio 2015 with message: "The 'prepare' script failed with status code -1073741819."

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, asp.net-core, publish, dnx

When publishing my asp.net 5 project, the output directory stays empty and I get the error: "The 'prepare' script failed with status code -1073741819."

Here are my publish settings:

- Publish target: "File System"
- Target location: "D:\Users\cseedj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Publish"
- Configuration: Debug
- DNX Version: Default (cnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4)

And here is the full output:

```
Connecting to D:\Users\cseedj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Publish...
Environment variables:
Path=D:\Users\cseedj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MvcDebug-Tweaking\src\MvcDebug\.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\cseedj\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4\bin\dnu.cmd publish "D:\Users\cseedj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MvcDebug-Tweaking\src\MvcDebug" --out "C:\Users\cseedj\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp" --configuration Debug --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4 --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --quiet
[09:07:41] Using gulpfile D:\Users\cseedj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MvcDebug-Tweaking\src\MvcDebug\gulpfile.js
[09:07:41] Starting 'clean'...
[09:07:41] Finished 'clean' after 650 μs
[09:07:41] Starting 'copy'...
[09:07:41] Finished 'copy' after 17 ms
The 'prepare' script failed with status code -1073741819.
```

Now when I copy the dnu command and execute it in a command line, it works fine: I get the files in the publish folder (well actually I still get an error 500 with the published code, but that's another question).

I also tried to run Visual Studio as Administrator too be sure it was not a filesystem rights related issue, but that doesn't help...

So why does the "publish" fail in VS and how can I make it work ?
And also a subsidiary question, why does it publish in a Temp directory and not in the Target location ?

---

Versions info:

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC, Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL
- My project uses beta4 versions of asp.net frameworks

Answer (score 16):

**This information is current as of beta-8.**

The `project.json` file allows for you to specify scripts which should run in  response to certain packaging (DNX Utility/`dnu`) events. In the default Visual Studio templates for Asp.Net 5 projects, the `project.json` file specifies any scripts which should run when you attempt to publish your app:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
```

In this example, four commands will run when you attempt to publish: `npm install`, `bower-install`, `gulp clean` and `gulp min`.

In most cases, when the `prepublish` task fails it is due to an error in your client-side build process (i.e. in your gulpfile.js). In my case, it was because I renamed a gulp task created by the Visual Studio template, without updating the `project.json` file. When I attempted to publish `gulp min` command was executed, but no `min` task was found in my `gulpfile.js`, resulting in the error. See this Github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/841) for more information.

Unfortunately, the available events that can be hooked into are poorly documented at this time. I believe the `prepare` script has since been renamed to `prepublish` as of beta-6 (see this Github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/805)). The error I received as of beta-8 is:

> The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 1.